# Ajax response appending in a table

Tags: html, ajax, django

I am doing a django project where in in ajax, i am calling my function and getting response in array then  i am appending those response in my html table.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/home',
                data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                success: function(data){
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                var trHTML = '';
                if (res.code == '200'){
                    for(i in res.data){
                    console.log(res.data)
                    console.log(res.data[i].id);
                    trHTML +=
                            '<tr><td><div><img src='
                            + res.data[i].poster_url + '>'
                            + '</td><td><div>'
                            + res.data[i].name
                            + '</div><div></div></td><td>'
                            + res.data[i].content_types_id
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + 'Africa'
                            + '</td><td><ul>'
                            + '</ul><td>';

                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Cart is empty');
                }
                $('#table-list').append(trHTML);


                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                },


            })
        })

    </script>
```

html codes

```
<table id="table-list" class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                        <thead class="cf">
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10%">&nbsp;</th>
                                <th width="30%" class="numeric">File Name</th>
                                <th width="15%" class="numeric">Content Type</th>
                                <th width="16%" class="numeric">Geo Rights</th>
                                <th width="16%" class="numeric">License</th>
                                <th width="13%" class="numeric">Action</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-title=""><div class="product"><img src="{% static 'images/p1.jpg' %}"></div></td>
                                <td data-title="File Name">
                                <div class="fl">The Lost World: Jurassic Park</div>
                                <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-white"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Upload Video</button></div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Content Type">Video</td>
                                <td data-title="Geo Rights">Asia Pacific, Africa</td>
                                <td data-title="License">Active Licenses:16</td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle" data-title="Action">
                                <ul class="action_icon">
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
```

But problem is when i append in front-end it shows only those columns while i want button section and action section to be intact.But i am not able to achieve it, how can i do so?

Comment: If this code actually does anything, it's not clear why, since you're appending to something with the ID `table-list`, which doesn't appear in the HTML you've posted. It's also not clear form your description what the problem is.

Comment: @kungphu sorry typing mistake please see my updated question.

Comment: It looks like you should be appending to `tbody`, not the table itself, but I'm still not sure what the problem is. _But problem is when i append in front-end it shows only those columns while i want button section and action section to be intact._ What does this mean? If it means you want the rows you're adding to have "Upload Video" buttons, you'll need to include that HTML in each row you're appending. If that's not it, please clarify the expected behavior and the incorrect behavior you're actually seeing.

Comment: @kungphu yes yes, you pointed it out exactly, i need upload video buttons to be visible also ,but the code i have written above is not showing, so what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/home',
            data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(data){
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                var trHTML = '';
                if (res.code == '200'){
                    for(i in res.data){
                        console.log(res.data)
                        console.log(res.data[i].id);
                        trHTML = $(`<tr>
                            <td><div><img src= ${res.data[i].poster_url}></td> 
                            <td><div>${res.data[i].name}</div><div></div></td> 
                            <td>${res.data[i].content_types_id}</td>
                            <td>Africa</td>
                            <td><ul>
                                  <li><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></li>
                                  <li><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></li>
                                  <li><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></li>
                                 </ul>
                            <td></tr>`);
                         $('#table-list').append(trHTML);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Cart is empty');
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
        })
    })
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
    <thead class="cf">
         <tr>
            <th width="30%" class="numeric">File Name</th>
            <th width="15%" class="numeric">Content Type</th>
            <th width="16%" class="numeric">Geo Rights</th>
            <th width="16%" class="numeric">License</th>
            <th width="13%" class="numeric">Action</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="table-list"></tbody>
</table>
```